# Could not update .ICEauthority file

Tags: authentication, fedora, sudo

Recently I changed the permissions of the file system and gave myself all the rights. I logged out of the system and I couldn't log back in. I got the error message

```
Could not update ICEauthority file /home/marundu/.ICEauthority</>
```

I did a live boot with a Fed 17 disc and replaced my .ICEauthority file with the live-user version and it worked for a time, until I logged out again. Now, the login progress screen is all that shows. I can log into command mode (Ctrl-Alt-F2) but I can't sudo - I get the error messages:

```
sudo:/usr/libexec/sudoers.so must be only writable by owner
```

and

```
sudo: fatal error. Unable to load plugins.
```

Comment: I found out what was wrong. My file system was broken. I changed the permissions and that's when it went downhill.

Comment: Did you fix it?  I tried a couple of solutions posted but none worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a good link on Ubuntu: 
[Ask Ubuntu: ICEauthority permissions problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55568/could-not-update-iceauthority-file-after-login-independent-of-gnome)

Some things to note:

- I tried the obvious things like changing file permissions, but found my whole home directory was somehow owned by root.  I believe this was due to a failed package update.
- I used a recovery disk (Knoppix ISO) for ease of use: Better UI
- When mounting the bad home partition, I used the most common Linux file type (Ext4)
- I used '`sudo mount -o r,w -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt`'
- When changing ownership, I used the numeric user:group specification, since the recovery disk doesn't have the symbolic users and groups: '`sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /mnt/home/userdir`'
- I verified that `/home/userdir` had `rwx` for owner, `r-x` for group / other.  This is noted as a valid set of permissions for ICEauthority; others can work.  See the linked discussion.

Hope that helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

I got the “Could not update ICEauthority file” error and found that my home partition was in "Read-Only" mode. Thus, this error made sense.

The real question was what caused the "Read-Only" attribute on the partition. I ran "dmesg | read-only" and found that there were serious errors with the file system on my home partition which the kernel had set to "read-only during the boot process.

I then booted from a USB key (CDROM would do as well) and ran "sudo fsck /dev/sdXY" where /dev/sdXY is the partition containing my home directory. fsck corrected a number of file system errors on my home partition.

I then reboot after removing the USB key/CDROM and the problem went away.

Bottom line: Check if your home partition has file system errors. They might be the cause of this error. If so, run fsck from an external device on the partition containing your home directory.